# How can I find the inverse Fourier transform of $e^{x^2}$ and similar functions?

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm honestly clueless; I tried writing it as ${\lmoustache}_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {e^{x^2}} {e^{ix}} {dx}$ , but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Do you mean $e^{-x^2}$? You wrote $e^{x^2}$, which increases to infinity rather than converging to zero as $|x| \to \infty$, so by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, it is not the Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function (i.e. it can't be the Fourier transform of something via the integral definition). It is also not an $L^2$ function, so it can't be the Fourier transform of an $L^2$ function. So you have to specify in what sense you are defining the Fourier transform in this context.

Comment: Assuming you meant $e^{-x^2}$, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1268566/169852

Answer (score 3):

I think this integral does not exist as your function does not stay bounded for $x\to \infty$.

Maybe your are missing a minus sign? If it was a minus you could do the follwing. You are also missing a parameter if this is a fourrier inverse transform (something like time, I will also leave it out as it does not change the method).

But $-x^2+2\frac{i}{2}x=-x^2+2\frac{i}{2}x-\frac{i^2}{4}+\frac{i^2}{4}=-(x-\frac{i}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}$

Introduce substitution $u=x-\frac{i}{2}$ and $du = dx$. Note also the changed integration bounds. Try to evaluate the integral using contour integration.

$$\int_{-\infty-i/2}^{\infty-i/2}e^{-u^2}e^{-1/4}du$$
This integral should be similar due, to Cauchy's Integral Theorem, to (use a rectangular contour along the real axis that goes down -i/2 and traces along an parallel to the real axis and gets back to the real axis):
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}e^{-1/4}du$$

Note that I am not sure if it is exactly the previous integral but it should be something similar.

This can be solved by multipling it by itself and using polar coordinates.

Comment: +1 You might consider referencing Cauchy's Integral Theorem, which permits the contour defomation.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but aren't you also missing a parameter? Since the OP specified Fourier transform, surely the intent was something like $e^{ixt}$ instead of $e^{ix}$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Sorry, I never studied complex analysis rigorously :D. Do you mean that a closed contour on a region where the function is holomorphic vanishes?

Comment: @Bungo: I don't think that this will change the the method drastically. That is why i left it out.

Comment: @MrYouMath For a function $f(z)$ that is analytic in and on a closed, rectifiable, closed-contour $C$, then $\oint_C f(z)\,dz=0$