# Identity involving infinite sum of exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please help me prove the identity $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi\alpha n^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2/\alpha}.$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Poisson summation formula?

Comment: Could you give us some more context?  Where did you encounter this identity?  What have you tried?  Is there any approach that you expect should work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The  [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) is no more than the Fourier series theorem

Let $$f(x) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty e^{-a \pi (x-m)^2}$$ the periodized Gaussian. What is its Fourier series ? It is $$g(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{2 i \pi n x}\quad \text{with} \quad c_n = \int_0^1 f(x)e^{-2i \pi n x}dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a \pi x^2} e^{-2i \pi n x}dx = a^{-1/2}e^{-\pi n^2 /a}$$
 (there are [many methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267007/inverse-fourier-transform-of-gaussian) for showing $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a \pi x^2} e^{-2 \pi b x}dx = a^{-1/2}e^{\pi b^2 /a}$, my favourite one being to complete the square assuming $b$ is real, and extending to $b \in \mathbb{C}$ by analytic continuation)

Of course since $f(x)$ is smooth, we know its Fourier series converges uniformly so that 
$$\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty e^{-a \pi (x-m)^2} = f(x) = g(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a^{-1/2}e^{-\pi n^2 /a} e^{2 i \pi n x}$$

Taking $x=0$ we get the desired identity.